# How do I get all labels from Visual Source Safe

Tags: visual-sourcesafe

Yes - still using Visual Source Safe.

I know you can 'get by label' when searching for specific label text. But I want to get all labels that were applied since a specific date. Can that be done?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's doable. You can right-click $/, click Show History. In the History Options dialog, check 'Recursive', 'Includes Labels' + 'Labels Only', specify the time range and you should get the results you want.